# When are the random variables $X$ and $f(X)$ jointly continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Two continuous random variables are said to be jointly continuous if they have a joint probability density function (or equivalently you can state it in terms of absolute continuity with respect to two-dimensional Lebesgue measure).  Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, and let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable function.  My question is, for what functions $f$ are $X$ and $f(X)$ jointly continuous?

I know $f$ can't be the identity function or the absolute value function, so what can it be?  If it's not possible to state a general condition for it, does anyone know of particular examples?  I'm just trying to better understand the notion of joint continuity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never.  The joint distribution of $(X,f(X))$ is always singular to Lebesgue measure.

The random vector $(X, f(X))$ always takes values in the graph of $f$, i.e. the set $G_f = \{(x,f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.  It is an exercise to verify that whenever $f$ is a Borel function, the set $G_f$ is Borel.  Then it follows from Fubini's theorem that $G_f$ has measure zero (every vertical section consists of one point and so has measure zero).

Comment: Hmm, is it possible for there to be two Borel functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are jointly continuous?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yes.  For example, given a real number $x$ in $[0,1]$ with decimal (or binary) expansion $x = 0.x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 \dots$, let $f(x) = 0.x_1 x_3 x_5\dots$ and $g(x) = 0.x_2 x_4 x_6 \dots$.  Then if $X \sim U(0,1)$, you may check that $f(X), g(X)$ are iid $U(0,1)$, and their joint distribution is absolutely continuous.

Comment: OK, is it possible for $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ to be dependent but jointly continuous?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Yes.  With $f,g$ as above, let $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and consider $(f(X), h(X))$ which is uniformly distributed over a parallelogram.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.